# Third cyclotomic field equal to 12th?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am reading Marcus's Number Fields and I've come across the following: Moreover, the third cyclotomic field is equal to the sixth: If we set $\omega=e^{2\pi i/6}$, then $\omega=-\omega^4=-(\omega^2)^2$, which shows that $\mathbb{Q}[\omega]=\mathbb{Q}[\omega^2]$".

However, doesn't this also show that $\mathbb{Q}[\omega]=\mathbb{Q}[\omega^4]$? since $\mathbb{Q}[\omega^4]\subseteq\mathbb{Q}[\omega]$ is clear and the above calculation implies the reverse inclusion?

Comment: $\phi(12)=4\ne2=\phi(6)=\phi(3)$.

Comment: I understand. But just set theoretically, why isn't what I've written above correct?

Comment: What you have written is correct. But $\Bbb{Q}(\omega^4)$ is not the twelfth cyclotomic field. That would be $\Bbb{Q}(\omega^{1/2})$ (still with $\omega=e^{2\pi i/6}$)..

Answer (score 1):

In fact, $\mathbb{Q}[\omega^n]=\mathbb{Q}[\omega]$ iff $3 \not \mid n$ and is $\mathbb{Q}$ otherwise.
This is because if $3 \not \mid n$, $\omega^n=u1/2+vi\sqrt{3}/2$, $u, v \in \{+1, -1\}$, so $\mathbb{Q}[\omega^n]=\mathbb{Q}[i\sqrt{3}]$ for each of those $n$.